# Advice needed, commercializing an Arduino Due project

Tags: arduino-due, electronics

We have a project using an Arduino Due, and we are looking to commercialize the project. How would one typically proceed? Would you use the Arduino Due inside the project? This seems very amateur.
Using another Arduino is not an option due to the number of interrupts, number of pins, and processing power required.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the kind of project you are doing. If the Due is just minor part (say you are producind 3D printer) and you plan to do like tens of the devices, I would consider using it, but probably would solder it in for good contact reliability. Maybe put it inside a box too, so nothing can short anything on the board. (And then the Due is not in plain sight).

If it is mainly Due with some sensors around and you want to sell thousands of them, then I would make extra PCB for it, containing everything what is possible on one board. (Like @Majenko suggested.)

Anyway I made a lot of PCB in my kitchen (yes, literally) for my "Arduino" projects, even when I made only 1 or 2 devices just for me. Every of them worked just fine. It is not so dificult to do if you are not pushing some limits too hard. Even Due small chip can be soldered by hands and with some basic tools on your eating table.

But if you lack the skills, hiring contractor (or found company, which does that) may be cheaper in terms of your time and number of devices destroyed before getting the skill and customers complaining about devices broken after short time use.

Answer (score 2):

There's two routes you can take.

First route:

1. Get the Due schematics.
2. Remove the parts you don't need.
3. Add to it the new components for your product.
4. Lay out the PCB design.
5. Get the PCB manufactured.
6. Solder all the components on.
7. Test it and go back to step 2/3 as required.

Second route:

1. Hire a contractor that knows the SAM3X and can do it all for you.